# Firebase Realtime Database rules are disallowing write from authenticated user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm having an issue with the Firebase Realtime Database rules. I register a new user with `mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`. In the `onCompleteMethod` i want to add my own user-object in the Realtime Database. 
I'm doing this, because each user has additional information to email/password.

After i check

```
FirebaseUser fireUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if(fireUser == null) {
    //do something
} else {
    createNewUser(fireUser);
}
```

the Method

```
private void createNewUser(FirebaseUser fireUser) {
        // Build the user-object.
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserId(fireUser.getUid());
        user.setUsername(name);
        user.setSex(sex);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setAge(time);
        user.setImageUri("");

        // Create database connection and reference.
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabaseRef.child("users").child(fireUser.getUid()).setValue(user);
    }
```

is called. But for some reason this DatabaseError is thrown:

```
W/RepoOperation: setValue at /users/9i6loj4BlCWkgkXOULWxbCSlvnx1 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

According to my understanding if the FirebaseUser isn't null - he is logged in and therefore my rules declared in Firebase

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

will allow the user to write the Database. However this code just works when I change my rules to `".read": "true"` and `".write": "true"`.

So my question is: What am i doing wrong here? I only want authenticated users to read/write.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

```
@Override
 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
     if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
         loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     } else {
         loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         FirebaseUser fireUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
         if(fireUser == null) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

         // Send verification mail
         sendVerificationEmail(fireUser);

         // Create a new User!
         createNewUser(fireUser);

         //start intent and sign out.
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
         FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your post to include the body of your `onComplete()` method?  That will make more clear the execution path to `createNewUser()`.

Comment: I added the onComplete method. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database writes do not complete synchronously. You're signing out before the database operation has time to complete:

```
     //start intent and sign out.
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
     FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();  // <== Can't do this here!
     startActivity(intent);
     finish();
```

In `createNewUser()`, you can add a `CompletionListener` with a log statement to the `setValue()` call to see when the write completes.  You could also add an `AuthStateListener` with log statement to detect when sign-in/sign-outs complete.  Those logs should confirm that the sign-out is completing before the DB write.